# ODBC Remote connectioon problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, odbc, connection

I'm trying to set a connection through ODBC to an SQl Server Express 2005 instance
the following connection string is working fine when I use it on the same machine

Conn string: "DSN=_Vendas;TrustedSecurity = yes;";

I have an ASP.NET application that needs to use the same connection remotel, and this fails

Exception: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

any configuration needed on SQl Server Express? Or is anything missing in the conn string?
tks

PS: already set Remote connections to use TCP\IP and named Pipes

Comment: Can we assume that the DSN is defined on the web server?

Answer (score 0):

I'd hazard a guess that you've defined the data source "_Vendas" on the 'local' machine but haven't defined it on the 'remote' machine.  Go into ODBC Administrator on the 'remote' machine and define the DSN as you've defined it on the 'local' machine and try it again.

Comment: yeah, I defined it as "User DSN" when I should have done it as "System DSN"... well, maybe it's because it's monday... =P